# Finding Document Properties in a pdf file with right clicking

Tags: pdf, document, file-properties

How can I find the information (Document Properties) linked to a pdf document showing the date created or modified. I can find this whenever I right-click in Windows but not with Linux. I know there must be a way.

Comment: What is your operating system? Which file manager are you using? As it stands, your question is incomplete and unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 open your pdf and select the menu in the top right hand corner:

[image]

From the menu select `Properties`

Not a right click as requested but the way to get properties all the same. The right click performs a different function.

Comment: Found it under File in Mint. Thank you!!!